# geometric description of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have matrix:
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}-\frac13&\frac23&\frac23\\\frac23&-\frac13&\frac23\\\frac23&\frac23&-\frac13\end{matrix}\right]$$
The eigenvalues and vectors is: $λ_1 = 1$ given vector $v_1 =(1 , 1, 1) λ_2 = λ_3 = -1$ gives vectors $v_2 =(-1, 1, 0)$ and $v_3 =(-1, 0, 1)$.
The question is "Give a geometric description of the linear transformation $T(x) = A*x$".

I took

$T(v_1) = A*v_1 = r_1$

$T(v_2) = A*v_2 =r_2$

$T(v_3) = A*v_3 =r_3$

I found that $r_1 =(1, 1, 1)$,
$r_2 =(1, -1, 0)$ and
$r_3 =(1, 0, -1)$ I see that $r_1 = v_1$, so I think nor rotation or mirror.
I take $v_2 + v_3 = (-2, 1, 1)$
And $T(v_2 + v_3) = r_1 + r_2 = (2, -1, -1)$.

Is the solution correct? And what can I see about rotation and mirror?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @Shaun can you help me now?

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry; good luck though!

Comment: @Shaun ok, thank you

Comment: There must be an error in computing the eigenvectors, because this is a symmetric matrix, so its eigenvectors must be orthogonal to each other.  However $(-1, 1, 0)$ is not orthogonal to $(-1, 0, 1) $.

Comment: @ghasheem There is no error. The eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ is the plane $x+y+z=0$ and a basis of it is not necessarily orthogonal. For a symmetric matrix, the only thing you can say is that the eigen*spaces* are orthogonal to eachother.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

With this sort of question, the first thing you do after finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors is looking at the eigenspaces.

Notice that $\lambda_1=1$ appears only once as a root of the characteristic polynomial, so the corresponding eigenspace $V_1$ has $\dim(V_1)=1$ and can be found as
$$V_1=Span(\ v_1=(1,1,1))$$
therefore it is a line through the origin.

For $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=-1$ we obtain the eigenspace $V_{-1}$, and you can easily check that $\dim(V_{-1})=2$ just by looking at the vectors you found,$v_2 =(-1, 1, 0)$ and $v_3 =(-1, 0, 1)$, that are clearly independent. So you have
$$V_{-1}=Span(\ v_2 =(-1, 1, 0)\ ,\ v_3 =(-1, 0, 1)\ )$$
therefore it is a plane through the origin.

Now we have a trasformation that leaves unaltered all the points on the line $V_1$ and reflects across the origin all the points on the plane $V_{-1}$, so we may think that T(x) is just the reflection across the line $V_1$. To check this we do one final calculation: we check that $V_1$ is in fact orthogonal to the plane $V_{-1}$:
$$\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle=0 \hspace{2cm} \langle v_1,v_3 \rangle=0$$
And this is what we needed to confirm our result.

Comment: Your theorem "If a trasformation has eigenvalues that consist of only +1
 and −1
 then it is an isometry" is false.

Comment: It is false even in $\Bbb R^2.$

Comment: [Oblique symmetries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_(geometry)#Non-isometric_symmetries) + $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Please read the link you sent.

Comment: I did, and moreover gave you an example of such an oblique symmetry. This is a counterexample.

Comment: And it is, indeed, a reflection.

Comment: It is not an isometry.

Comment: I apologize. The theorem goes in the other direction: "if it is an isometry then its eignvalues are $+1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You found that $\ker(A-I)$ is the line $L$ spanned by $v_1$ and $\ker(A+I)$ is the plane spanned by $v_2,v_3$.

Note moreover that $A$ is a symmetric matrix hence these two complementary eigenspaces are orthogonal (but you could also have noticed it before choosing a basis for $\ker(A+I),$ when you first found that its equation was $x+y+z=0,$ i.e. $\ker(A+I)=v_1^\perp$).

Therefore, $A$ is the [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) across $L.$

Answer (score 0):

Define $ u = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} [ 1, 1, 1]^T $

Then

$ A = 2 u u^T - I $

if $ x $ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then

$ u u^T x $ is the projection of $x$ onto the axis $u$.  The reflection of $x$ about $u$ is

$ x' = u u^T x - (x - u u^T x) = 2 u u^T x - x = (2 u u^T - I) x $

Hence $A$ is a reflection matrix about the axis defined by the unit vector $u$.